# Connection to IBM message hub using C# and Confluent

Tags: c#, confluent-platform, message-hub

I'm trying to create producer and consumer apps using IBM message hub. For the producer i'm using the following code:

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                { "bootstrap.servers", brokerList },
                { "group.id", "simple-csharp-producer" },
                { "client.id", "some string for id such as FR45fHth..." },
                {"api.version.request","true" },
                {"sasl.mechanisms","PLAIN" },
                {"sasl.username","the first 16 charachters of the client.id" },
                {"sasl.password","the other characters left" }
            };

            using (var producer = new Producer<Null, string>(config, null, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
            {
              ....
            }
```

for the consumer i'm using similar config properties.

the rest of the code for the consumer:

```
using (var consumer = new Consumer<Null, string>(config, null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
            {
                consumer.Assign(new List<TopicPartitionOffset> { new TopicPartitionOffset(topics, 0, 0) });

                while (true)
                {
                    Message<Null, string> msg;
                    if (consumer.Consume(out msg, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {msg.Topic} Partition: {msg.Partition} Offset: {msg.Offset} {msg.Value}");
                    }
                }
            }
```

and for the producer:

```
using (var producer = new Producer<Null, string>(config, null, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{producer.Name} producing on {topicName}. q to exit.");

                string text;
                while ((text = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
                {
                    var deliveryReport = producer.ProduceAsync(topicName, null, text);
                    deliveryReport.ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Partition: {task.Result.Partition}, Offset: {task.Result.Offset}");
                    });
                }

                // Tasks are not waited on synchronously (ContinueWith is not synchronous),
                // so it's possible they may still in progress here.
                producer.Flush(Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
```

Anyhow, it didn't work, there is no sign for sending of getting anything...
what is missing?
or what can i use for it to work?

The Logs i get:

> *sasl_ssl://kafka03-prod02.messagehub.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net:9093/bootstrap:
>   Failed to initialize SASL authentication: SASL mechanism "PLAIN" not
>   supported on platform
>
> *1/1 brokers are down

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the Confluent C# client myself, but as far as I know it's based on librdkakfa, so you'll at least need a few more configurations to connect to Message Hub:

- `security.protocol` set to `SASL_SSL`
- `ssl.ca.location` set to the path of your CA certificates

Answer (score 0):

The settings that Mickael has posted are correct.

However if you are running on Windows - to get SASL/SSL support (required for Message Hub) you need librdkafka 0.11

With librdkafka 0.9.5 you can't connect to MH from Windows

Comment: see also this post - to find out how to set the certificate path option

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820430/ibm-message-hub-communciation-with-c-sharp-confluent-api/44821846#44821846

Comment: paste your logs (with debug=all maybe) please so we can see if it's a connection or authentication problem

Comment: this message in the logs
`SASL mechanism "PLAIN" not supported on platform`

suggests that librdkafka has not been built with SASL support.

As said, for Windows you need librdkafka 0.11
on Linux, you need to have libsasl2-dev installed

Comment: Yes, I don't follow... what about them?

Comment: Which OS are you on ?

to have SASL support :

If Windows - you need librdkafka 0.11 
If Linux - you need libsas2-dev
If mac - you need brew openssl and to build against its header/lib files

Comment: I'm using Windows and i'm using linrdkafka 0.11